# How to create simple Offline payment gateway for WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Good afternoon, I want to make simple copy of Cash on Delivery (COD) payment method in my store and rename it to Coupon on Delivery. 
How to implement it?

Up
I have tried this code, but it shows error 500 on WC settings page:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: My New WooCommerce Gateway
 * Plugin URI:
 * Description: WooCommerce gateway to ....
 * Author: .....
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author URI: https://example.org/
 * Text Domain: woocommerce-my-gateway
 * Domain Path: /languages/
 */

add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'init_my_gateway_class' );

function init_my_gateway_class() {
    if ( !class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) ) return;
    class WC_Gateway_COD_Renamed extends WC_Payment_Gateway {
    }
}

function add_my_gateway_class( $methods ) {
    $methods[] = 'WC_Gateway_my_gateway';
    return $methods;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_payment_gateways', 'add_my_gateway_class' );

function my_load_textdomain(){
    load_plugin_textdomain( 'woocommerce-my-gateway', false, dirname( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/languages/' ) );
}
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'my_load_textdomain');
```

[Source of code](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/656713/204661)

Comment: Added to the question

Comment: It shows error 500 in WooCommerce Settings page.

Comment: The class `WC_Gateway_my_gateway` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your main plugin file you can include the class and filter the gateways at the same time:

```
function add_my_gateway_class( $methods ) {
    include( 'class-wc-gateway-cod-renamed.php');
    $methods[] = 'WC_Gateway_COD_Renamed';
    return $methods;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_payment_gateways', 'add_my_gateway_class' );
```

There's no real need to check if WooCommerce is active this way as `woocommerce_payment_gateways` only exists if WooCommerce is running.

Then in another file called `class-wc-gateway-cod-renamed.php` you can define your class:

```
class WC_Gateway_COD_Renamed extends WC_Gateway_COD {

    /**
     * Setup general properties for the gateway.
     */
    protected function setup_properties() {
        $this->id                 = 'coupon-on-delivery';
        $this->icon               = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_coupon-on-deliver_icon', '' );
        $this->method_title       = __( 'Coupon on delivery', 'your-plugin' );
        $this->method_description = __( 'Have your customers pay with a coupon upon delivery.', 'your-plugin' );
        $this->has_fields         = false;
    }

    /**
     * Initialise Gateway Settings Form Fields.
     */
    public function init_form_fields() {
        $shipping_methods = array();

        foreach ( WC()->shipping()->load_shipping_methods() as $method ) {
            $shipping_methods[ $method->id ] = $method->get_method_title();
        }

        $this->form_fields = array(
            'enabled' => array(
                'title'       => __( 'Enable/Disable', 'your-plugin' ),
                'label'       => __( 'Enable coupon on delivery', 'your-plugin' ),
                'type'        => 'checkbox',
                'description' => '',
                'default'     => 'no',
            ),
            'title' => array(
                'title'       => __( 'Title', 'your-plugin' ),
                'type'        => 'text',
                'description' => __( 'Payment method description that the customer will see on your checkout.', 'your-plugin' ),
                'default'     => __( 'coupon on delivery', 'your-plugin' ),
                'desc_tip'    => true,
            ),
            'description' => array(
                'title'       => __( 'Description', 'your-plugin' ),
                'type'        => 'textarea',
                'description' => __( 'Payment method description that the customer will see on your website.', 'your-plugin' ),
                'default'     => __( 'Pay with coupon upon delivery.', 'your-plugin' ),
                'desc_tip'    => true,
            ),
            'instructions' => array(
                'title'       => __( 'Instructions', 'your-plugin' ),
                'type'        => 'textarea',
                'description' => __( 'Instructions that will be added to the thank you page.', 'your-plugin' ),
                'default'     => __( 'Pay with coupon upon delivery.', 'your-plugin' ),
                'desc_tip'    => true,
            ),
            'enable_for_methods' => array(
                'title'             => __( 'Enable for shipping methods', 'your-plugin' ),
                'type'              => 'multiselect',
                'class'             => 'wc-enhanced-select',
                'css'               => 'width: 400px;',
                'default'           => '',
                'description'       => __( 'If coupon upon delivery is only available for certain methods, set it up here. Leave blank to enable for all methods.', 'your-plugin' ),
                'options'           => $shipping_methods,
                'desc_tip'          => true,
                'custom_attributes' => array(
                    'data-placeholder' => __( 'Select shipping methods', 'your-plugin' ),
                ),
            ),
            'enable_for_virtual' => array(
                'title'             => __( 'Accept for virtual orders', 'your-plugin' ),
                'label'             => __( 'Accept coupon if the order is virtual', 'your-plugin' ),
                'type'              => 'checkbox',
                'default'           => 'yes',
            ),
       );
    }
}
```

Extend the `WC_Gateway_COD` class so that you can inherit methods from it and only override the methods that have to do with the naming of things.

Answer (score 2):

In WooCommerce plugin, you can enable payment gateway COD from admin section:

Admin  >> WooCommerce >> Settings >> Checkout >> Cash on delivery.

Check option for enable COD.

Please refer below link for create offline payment gateway.

[How to Create A WooCommerce Payment gateway](https://www.skyverge.com/blog/how-to-create-a-simple-woocommerce-payment-gateway/)

Comment: Thanks) but the trouble is, that I need both COD and new payment method which is the same as COD, but have another name (Coupon on Delivery). In other words I need 2 offline payment methods.